# Can a pull erase all changes in the working directory?

Tags: git

New to git (through my new job) and being instructed to "just do a pull *before* you commit", I did so. Much to my surprise, all changes in my working directory disappeared.

- How did this happen?
- Where did these file go?
- Is there a way to
  restore them?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't they say "pull before you *push*" instead?

Comment: You should pull before you PUSH as choroba said. If you pull before you commit, all your code will be wiped off! commit commit commit always!

Comment: `pull` just overwrites the uncommitted local changes. You are able to recover something in your repo if that 'something' was added and committed earlier.

Comment: @choroba No, they said "pull before you commit". Actually, their workflow (part of a Jenkins-based CI) is: "Pull > Commit > Pull > Push". I am still struggling to understand that. Thanks for any tip you can share.

Comment: @VeryObjective I work with Jenkins based CI all day and night :) Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `git pull` is effectively an alias for `git fetch` and `git merge`. Whoever was instructing you probably did a poor job, because `git pull` right before you commit will indeed wipe out all your work. What they should have told you to do instead was commit, *then* `git pull`, or if you don't want a merge history use `git pull --rebase` instead. After that you can `git push`.

I don't believe there is any way to get back your un-committed work if it was overwritten by a merge initiated by `git pull`, unfortunately.

Also as a not-super-related friendly reminder, make sure every time before you start working on a new commit you `git pull` to get any commits anyone else has been working on.

Comment: Accepting +1. Thank you. Fortunately, since I never trust anything I don't *fully* understand, I kept a copy of my changes in a secret stash. :D  I will now know better thanks to your explanation.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds to me maybe like they were talking in the big picture, that you should `git pull` before you *make changes* so that your changes are to the latest code and not to something old. But then you commit and git pull again to update it even more and merge your new code in this time instead of editing it in.

Answer (score 6):

Never pull before you commit any valid changes. This will wipe off all your changes.

To retain your code, you have to commit, then pull, then finally push.

Follow these steps-

Add your files to the commit-

```
git add <filename>
```

Commit those files with a commit message-

```
git commit -m "added blah feature"
```

Then, Pull(preferably rebase) to get the latest code from the repo-

```
git pull --rebase
```

Then push(YAY!)-

```
git push -u origin master
```

About what they would have meant(looking at Jenkins CI thing you told)-

First pull the code(hard reset also maybe, as I do it sometimes) from repo to your local directory. Then if you have a separate branch or different local working directory, make changes from there to this new location(pull) and then commit your changes. Then finally push.

Hope it helps :) Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks +1. Fortunately, since I never trust anything I don't *fully* understand, I kept a copy of my changes in a secret stash. :D  I will now know better.

Comment: @VeryObjective  Updated answer now :) and yes, Stash is a good thing! :) Helps a lot.